# Database fail when php mysql app gets ported to web server

Tags: php, mysql, apache, mysql-error-1054

I am new to web development and after reading some reviews on web hosting from hacker news, I decided to try out nearlyfreespeech (NFS). I have been doing some offline development using PHP/MySQL/Apache on localhost and everything have been running well. Now, I am at the stage where I would like to port it to a web server.

Following their procedure, I got a MySQL process and created a new database using their built in Phpmyadmin. But, when I upload the entire project folder, I get this error:

> Code: Database Error  A database error
>   occurred.  Error message:
>   SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found:
>   1054 Unknown column
>   'Products.categoryID' in 'where clause

This tells me that the SQL queries are not able to access the database. I ran .sql file in phpmyadmin so I know that the database name is correct. I use $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] so that the paths will stay intact.

```
Code:
$doc_root = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']; 

// Get the application path 
$uri = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']; 
//echo "URI is $uri"; 
$dirs = explode('/', $uri); 
$app_path = '/' . $dirs[1] . '/'; 
//$app_path = '/' . $dirs[1] . '/' . $dirs[2] . '/'; 
// $app_path = '/' . $dirs[1] . '/' . $dirs[2] . '/' . $dirs[3] . '/' . $dirs[4] . '/'; 
//echo "APP_PATH is $app_path"; 

// Set the include path 
set_include_path($doc_root . $app_path);
```

I have a .php file which connects to the database and I have these filled in.

```
Code:
$dsn = 'mysql:host=yko.db;dbname=my_guitar_shop2'; 
$username = 'myphpmyadminusername'; 
$password = 'myphpmyadminpassword';
```

yko.db is the mysql process that I made and the database made using phpmyadmin is my_guitar_shop2. I looked at the phpmyadmin and confirmed that the database does exist.

So, I am stump right now. Everything seems to be working on localhost and it is not working on the web server.

I use netbeans as the IDE and followed their instructions upload the files which I put into /home/public/projectFolder

Is there any settings I need to look at or change to get this to work? I retried it using localhost and everything seems to work. What else in the source can I possibly look at to get this to work.

Thanks much!!!

PS: Alternatively, I would take a tutorial that will take a begineer from registering for a domain, setting up a web server, database, phpmyadmin, etc and then uploading projects using an IDE (netbeans, eclipse). I don't mind paying again for another web hosting. I just want to get it running and get my feet wet.

Comment: Does the column exist in the table? Are you 100% sure?

Comment: Can your query your db with "show databases;" from within a php file?

Comment: @Rudu: if the script couldn't connect to the server because the hostname is wrong, it'd say so. It wouldn't complain about a missing field.

Comment: @Rudu: Yea I agree with Marc B. When I have a wrong hostname and/or username/password combination, it would give me a different error. Foe example, using localhost.

Comment: @Pekka. Yes I am 100% sure. Because a lot of this code is from a book I bought and it provides a .sql file which I ran in phpmyadmin along with all the data. I also looked at the tables inside the database and made sure it exists.

Comment: @NickWeaver: I am not sure what you mean.

Comment: I mean, to send a query to your database, mysql_query("show databases;"); and dump the result of the query. It should list all available databases of your connection: it's just there to make sure your script "sees" the same dbs as phpMyAdmin. Look here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/show-databases.html.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using a DOT in your column name (`Products.categoryID` would indicate you are)... MySQL support for dots in column names started with version 5.1.6 (Reference: [Object Names](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/identifiers.html))

Might want to check your remote version (through phpmyadmin).